# How to use single array to implement 3 stacks

Tags: arrays, stack, typeid

Question: Implement 3 stacks using one array

I recently came across this question and went through a few different type of solutions.

Here are some solutions which I've seen:

1. Interleave positions in a stack, so something like:
   a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c3....

   This however isn't efficient if the stacks vary in size hugely, we'll just end    up wasting space.
2. Start 2 stack from alternate ends of the array and start the 3rd stack from the middle of the array and keep checking if they overlap each other

   This seems to be a better solution, however the solutions suggested that incase the 3rd stack starts to overlap with either Stack 1 or Stack 2, you change the direction of stack 3. But let's say Stack 1 and Stack 2 are both equal size = 1. And Stack 3 starts to over lap Stack 2, it will change direction and now it will overlap Stack 1. We can of course put conditions to check this, but again copying and changing directions is too much overhead in my view.
3. This is the solution I was thinking of, but I'm not sure if it would be the most efficient one. Maybe most space efficient, but not time (efficient)

   Supposing the elements of Stack 1 , 2 and 3 are all integers.

   1.I will insert elements one after another in the (double)array without any logic.

   2. When inserting :
      for stack 1 keep it integer, 
      for stack 2 make it double,
      for stack 3 make it float.
   3. And when searching/popping I start from position 1 and check type with value

Code:

```
double arr[100];
int stackPointer[3]; // keep track of last insertion point for respective stacks



void insertion(stackNumber,value){



  for(int i = 0; i<100; i++){
   if(arr[i]=='\0'){

   if (stackNumber==1)  arr[i] = (int)value;
  if (stackNumber==2)  arr[i] = (double)value;
  if (stackNumber==3)  arr[i] = (float)value;
 }


   if (stackNumber==1)  stackPointer[0] = i;
   if (stackNumber==2)  stackPointer[1] = i;
   if (stackNumber==3)  stackPointer[2] = i;

   } 
}


int popping(stackNumber){




for(int i = stackPointer[stackNumber]-1; i>=0 ; i-- ){

  if( typeid(arr[i]).name() ==  typeid(arr[stackPointer[stackNumber]]).name() )
   stackPointer[stackNumber] = i  
  }

 arr[ stackPointer[stackNumber]  ]  = '\0';  // pop this element
}
```

This isn't the cleanest / most correct code, but I hope I got my idea clear.

Comment: After popping all these value will `double`. But, of course, you can use some additional info about stack's elements to develop more efficient solutions. F.e. you can use 2 most significant bits of integer to mark elements (0 — empty, 1, 2, 3 — the number of the stack). It will work if your integers are not very large.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko do you say all will be double on popping because it is double array type.

Comment: Sure. In the line `if (stackNumber==1)  arr[i] = (int)value;` you have the implicit type conversion from `int` to `double`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some interest variants.

F.e. you can organize a stack like a heap with fixed-size blocks (pages). For instance, the size of each block can be 128 or 256 elements. The first element of each block (lets call it `header`) contains 0, if the block is empty, or 1, 2, 3 — the number of stack. The header can contain index of next and previous blocks, if you need a performance.

Such decision lets you use almost all the memory, excepting headers and two blocks of elements at worst. But it can be not so clear in implementation.

Of course, the size of block must be sufficient small compared the size of the entire stack.